# Sketch the region given in polar coordinates by $1\leq r\leq 2$, $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \pi$

Tags: calculus

Q) Sketch the region given in polar coordinates by $1\leq r\leq 2$, $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq  \pi$

Comments:

I find this question particularly difficult because of the format. I've had to plot polar coordinates in the form (r, theta) and sketch curves but I am unsure of how to go about sketching a region set up like this. I am just lost.

I am guessing that if I find the angles for theta first i can color in between the radius creating what looks like a cut out of a dough nut. Is this correct?

Any tips would be wonderful!

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct. Sketch the full doughnut first. The full doughnut is the region between 2 circles of given radii. Then find the lines that need to be drawn corresponding to the two given angles. Sketch the part of the full doughnut from the first line up to the second line radially.

Comment: Fantastic! I was so unsure. I appreciate you commenting. :)

Answer (score 2):

$1\le r\le 2$ by itself is a "washer" or annulus with inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$.

$\pi/4\le\theta\le \pi$  by itself sweeps out a circular wedge which starts at $\theta=\pi/4$ and ends at $\theta=\pi$.

Combining these two:

[image]